# Power Query: Custom Function to convert a single text comma delimited list input into a new list, "wrapped" in other text

Tags: function, powerquery, m

I'd appreciate help please.  I'm trying to write my first function in Power Query (in Poweer BI, not Excel) which takes a text string as an input and outputs it "wrapped in other text".

The input is a comma separated single
ie.

```
"GB02, NL01, IT05, FR03"
```

the desired output is:

```
"[Company].[GB02],[Company].[NL01],[Company].[IT05],[Company].[FR03]"
```

I've started by using the text split function whcih I've created a function called List2Table:

***List2Table:***

```
(InputText as text) =>
let 
SplitData = 
    
    Table.FromList(
        Text.Split(InputText,",")
        )

in SplitData
```

which when invoked...

```
= List2Table("GB02,NL01,IT05,FR03")
```

returns:

```
Column1
GB02
NL01
IT05
FR03
```

I now want to append the text

`"[Company].["`

....to the beginning of each value, and

`"]"`

....to the end, and then recombine into a single text string with each value separated by commas, but I dont know how to do this as part of the original function.

I've looked into this and I believe that this is achieved with the "each" operator, so I've tried this:

```
(InputText as text) =>
let 
SplitData = 
    
    Table.FromList(
        Text.Split(InputText,",")
        , each "[Company].[" & _ & "]")

in SplitData
```

but this gives the error:

```
An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "[Company].[GB02]" to type List.
Details:
    Value=[Company].[GB02]
    Type=[Type]
```

Any help greatly received

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing your desired output as a text string, not a table.

To create you output string from the input, you can simply use the `List.Transform` function.

eg:

```
(InputText as text)=>

let 
    SplitData = Text.Split(InputText,","),
    Process = List.Transform(SplitData, each "[Company].[" & _ & "]")
in 
    Text.Combine(Process,",")
```

As invoked:
[image]

If you want something else, please be more specific.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  was going round and round in circles